# include cc in php mail function

Tags: php, html-email, email-formats

When I`m trying to insert cc with the php mail function I get only message with the HTML part.

I`m using the following code

```
      $headers  = "From:someone@gmail.com\r\n";
      $headers .= "CC:test@gmail.com\r\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
  $to ="$x_email";
  $subject ="Your Order Confirmation";
      $bodyadmin=$messageadmin;
  $sentmail=mail($to, $subject, $bodyadmin, $headers);
```

Could any one please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please amend your question to make sense. What do you mean you only get the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers = "From: $from_email\r\nReply-To: $from_email";
$headers .= 'Cc: test@test.com\r\n';
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
```

Comment: I was going to suggest that CC is case sensitive and needed to be Cc. Do you know if I am correct in my thinking?

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```